# 3D matrix perspective transform

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am using shape from shading to generate a Digital Terrain Model (DTM) of an image taken using a camera mounted on a mobile platform. The algorithm written in Python seems to work reasonably well however the output is at an incline and a bit spherical so I'm suspecting that I need to remove perspective distortion and barrelling from the DTM.

The data is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21471588/SFS_DTM.txt) in case anyone is interested in having a go at this.

The camera is mounted at an inclination of 41 degrees and has the following camera and distortion matrices:

```
    cam_matrix = numpy.matrix([[246.00559,0.00000,169.87374],[0.00000,247.37317,132.21396],[0.00000,0.00000,1.00000]])
    distortion_matrix = numpy.matrix([0.04674, -0.11775, -0.00464, -0.00346, 0.00000])
```

How can I apply perspective transform and remove the barreling distortion from this matrix to obtain a flattened DTM?

I have attempted this using OpenCV but it doesn't work as OpenCv is expecting an image and the transforms simply move pixels around rather than manipulate their value. I have also researched Numpy and Scipy but haven't arrived to a conclusion or a solution yet. I am somewhat familiar with the theory behind these transforms but have mostly worked on 2D versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing?!?! not even a comment after 3 days?? I thought this was an easy problem to solve for the gurus on this site. Could I please have any comments as to whether this problem has been encountered before or whether finding a solution has any merit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a 4 x 4 transformation matrix which is inversible and allows a bi-directional tranformation between the two coordinate systems that you want.

If you know the three rotations `a`, `b` and `g`, about `x`, `y`, `z` respectively, using the right-hand rule. The `x0`, `y0`, `z0` are the translations between the origins of the two coordinate systems.

The transformation matrix is defined as:

```
T = np.array([[ cos(b)*cos(g), (sin(a)*sin(b)*cos(g) + cos(a)*sin(g)), (sin(a)*sin(g) - cos(a)*sin(b)*cos(g)), x0],
              [-cos(b)*sin(g), (cos(a)*cos(g) - sin(a)*sin(b)*sin(g)), (sin(a)*cos(g) + cos(a)*sin(b)*sin(g)), y0],
              [        sin(b), -sin(a)*cos(b), cos(a)*cos(b), z0]
              [ 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

To use it efficiently you should put your points in a 2-D array like:

```
orig = np.array([[x0, x1, ..., xn],
                 [y0, y1, ..., yn],
                 [z0, z1, ..., zn],
                 [ 1,  1, ...,  1]])
```

Then:

```
new = T.dot(orig)
```

will give you the transformed points.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, however I'm not sure I understand the "put your points in a 2-D array like" bit. My output is an array containing z values from the world frame which as you correctly pointed out, I need to transform into the camera frame.
So what are the x0 and y0 coming from in the "orig" array, keeping in mind that my image isn't square so the dimensions of x are bigger than the dimensions of y.

Comment: Thanks once again for your input. I managed to get the desired output using your solution, although I built the x0,x1... and y0,y1... matrix using ones as I only have a z0,z1... matrix which was rearanged in a 1D matrix before adding x and y.

Answer (score 1):

**Saullo G. P. Castro** has a great explanation.   This is the code I used with Python 3.8.  If you play around with the T = make_matrix(90,0,0,1,0,0) line you can see the changes to the XYZ positions in the orig matrix.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import math
'''If you know the three rotations a, b and g, about x, y, z respectively, using the 
right-hand rule.
The x0, y0, z0 are the translations between the origins of the two coordinate 
systems.'''
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175385/3d-matrix-perspective-transform/22311973#22311973

def make_matrix(roll,pitch,heading,x0,y0,z0):
    a = math.radians(roll)
    b = math.radians(pitch)
    g = math.radians(heading)

    T = np.array([[ math.cos(b)*math.cos(g), (math.sin(a)*math.sin(b)*math.cos(g) + 
    math.cos(a)*math.sin(g)), (math.sin(a)*math.sin(g) - 
    math.cos(a)*math.sin(b)*math.cos(g)), x0],
    [-math.cos(b)*math.sin(g), (math.cos(a)*math.cos(g) - 
    math.sin(a)*math.sin(b)*math.sin(g)), (math.sin(a)*math.cos(g) + 
    math.cos(a)*math.sin(b)*math.sin(g)), y0],
    [        math.sin(b), -math.sin(a)*math.cos(b), math.cos(a)*math.cos(b), z0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1]])
    return T

def load_orig():
    orig = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0],
                [ 1,  1, 1]])
    return orig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T = make_matrix(90,0,0,1,0,0)
    orig = load_orig()
    new = T.dot(orig)
    print(new)
```