# Is there a numpy function to perform coordinate transformations?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm developing some lecture notes on numerical methods in an ipython notebook, and I need to include some coordinate transformation functions. I've already coded these functions (below), but the details aren't exactly fundamental to the topic, and it would simplify the lecture if I could call pre-written functions.

I see the scipy image rotation function, but I just need coordinate translation and rotation. ie

```
# transform from global to panel coordinates
def transformXY( self, x, y ):
    xp = x-self.xc
    yp = y-self.yc
    xpp = xp*self.sx+yp*self.sy
    ypp = yp*self.sx-xp*self.sy
    return [ xpp, ypp ]

# rotate velocity back to global coordinates
def rotateUV( self, u, v):
    up = u*self.sx-v*self.sy
    vp = v*self.sx+u*self.sy
    return [ up, vp ]
```

In these, `sx` and `sy` are the unit tangent vector components.

Comment: you can also move your own functions into a separate .py file and import them from there. That way their internals are hidden in the notebook.

Comment: I'd say @PeterE's comment should be an accepted answer

Comment: @weymouth [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22311973/832621) it is shown how I implemented a general cartesian coordinate system transformation using NumPy

Comment: @weymouth Are these methods of a class? If not, you probably should not be using the name `self`.

Comment: @Roland. Yes, they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied and expanded from previous comment:

You can also move your own functions into a separate .py file and import them from there. That way their internals are hidden in the notebook.
If you place them in a file/module called e.g. `transformation.py` and place that file next to your notebook file , you can then import your functions with `from transformation import *`

As has been suggested in a now deleted answer, I would recommend using matrices for any transformation, especially rotations. This is in my opinion much clearer than element-wise modifications.

EDIT:
Afaik there are no predefined coordinate-transformation functions in numpy. In sympy there is [something](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/diffgeom.html), but I'm not sure how useful it is, it seams a bit much for a simple transformation.
For transformations via matrices google found me the this [module](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html), which appears to be quite comprehensive.

Comment: Using `import *` is usually a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386740/1461210)

Comment: @ali_m True enough. My point was more about the fact that the folder the notebook is in is searched for modules to import.

Comment: Yes, that would work for me, I guess. For posterity - is the answer to my question, "no".

Comment: You *can* also apply translations (basically *all* [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)) with matrices, if you use [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).